# Font rendering inconsistencies in browser

Tags: html, css, web, browser, fonts

I am currently working with a custom font and I am having rendering issues across mobile devices.  After some research, it seems as though it may be a baseline problem with the font itself.

Here is the code, the first button is the custom font and the second is arial:

```
<div>
        ITC Franklin Gothic Demi Compressed-> 
        <button style="padding:0 !important; margin: 0 !important;">start</button>
        <button style="padding:0 !important; margin: 0 !important; font-family: arial;">start</button> 
        <- arial
</div>
```

I removed all padding and margins, which renders as expected on chrome - desktop.

[Chrome - Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUKEx.png)

But not on Chrome on my Android phone.

[Chrome - Mobile (Desktop)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbljj.png)

As you can see, there is some padding on the custom font on a mobile device.

What could be the problem?

As a last resort, I could style them differently with CSS media queries.  My concern with this approach is devices with higher resolutions which may trigger the desktop styles and revert back to the original issue.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer the question from personal experience but a quick Google has given me this forum question and answer. The solution revolves around the use of the line-height property.

https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/desktop-vs-tablet-android-chrome-big-line-height-difference-i-think-related-to-high-density-screens/247286

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem.  The fonts that were sent to me weren't web fonts.  Once the web fonts were applied, they rendered consistently across different devices.